Баг со сворачиванием приложения при скроллинге в Web App на flet
Используя flet на python, столкнулся с проблемой сворачивания веб-приложения в телеграмм при скроллинге вертикально. Как это исправить? В интернете нашёл множество решений для js, но для flet - ничего
